Not receiving the full payload - WebService C#
I'm developing a WebService that receives a payload when I press on a button.
But Im only getting one line from the payload, not the full payload.
I tried this method:
[WebMethod]
public GetServiceOrderByDateResponse GetServiceOrderByDate(XmlElement Request)
{
    string xml = Request.OuterXml;
    Context.Response.Write(xml + "\n\n");

    // Rest of the code
}

is the method "Request.OuterXml" that is wrong?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
